# System.exe trying to connect microsoft ISP

Tags: windows-xp, firewall

When i connect to internet, I often get these firewall notification requests that system.exe is trying to connect

```
Process: System
Remote Address: 94.245.121.212, PROTO41
```

through PROTO41, the address isn't fixed, sometimes it is

```
Remote Address 94.245.121.221, PROTO41
```

OR

```
Remote Address 94.245.121.204, PROTO41
```

OR Any other but it is microsoft's as i resolved.

What's the purpose of it?

Comment: It could be any number of things including verify you have no pending updates and/or syncing your system clock.

Comment: I receive the updates with no problems, also tried sync my clock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to check, and I concur that those are Microsoft IP addresses. Here is my explanation the best that I understand it.

Protocol 41 is ISATAP, a protocol that connects IPv6 hosts/routers over IPv4 networks using a tunnel. ISATAP needs a server to create this tunnel, and apparently, Microsoft is providing that for Windows clients.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISATAP

http://isatap.org/

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd630627(WS.10).aspx

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverNIS/thread/09016c42-20c9-4a2c-90a6-50fb4eb00daa

Answer (score 2):

The process is called "System", **not** "System.exe". (It's part of the kernel and does not have a separate image file.)

Generally, [IPv4 protocol 41 is **"IPv6"**](http://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xml). It's not just ISATAP but also the more common [6to4](http://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xml)/6in4 tunnels. When Windows sees that you have an "external" IPv4 address assigned (i.e. *not* behind a NAT), it automatically tries to obtain a IPv6 connection using 6to4 tunnels. (Although 6to4 would normally use `192.88.99.1` as a tunnel server.)